# Branched too early, what to do?

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I was on a branch with one commit. I created a new branch, when I should have switched back to master first.

How do I remove the first commit of the new branch, without affecting the branch it was originally created on?

In effect, I want to move the initial commit of the new branch up by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important: before playing with `rebase`, either test commands on a copy of your repository, or learn how to use the reflog to undo changes to your repository.

You seem to be describing a situation like this:

```
master
*
|
|  b1    b2
*  * --- *
| / 
|/
*
```

and you instead want

```
master
*
| * b2
|/
*
| * b1
|/
*
```

In that case, rebase as follow:

```
git rebase --onto master^ b1 b2
```

This moves all the commits reachable from `b2` but *not* from `b1`, and roots them at the commit immediately before `master`. Note that you can really only count backwards from `master` to identify the proper stating place; you can't count forwards from the common ancestor of `b1` and `master`, because commits don't keep track of their children, only its parent(s).

Comment: I realised I just need to create a new branch from master and cherry-pick the commit I wanted from the first branch into the second. D'oh!